# How to deal with multiple data fields (MTD, YTD, ITD) in matrix columns?

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a matrix visual that has 3 data fields (MTD, YTD, ITD) in the columns section. When I drill down to each level they show exactly as they should (Pictures below for each level of drill down).

I do not wish to drill down to see each column. I want all columns displayed at once. I have tried things like removing stepped layout from row headers format and expanding all down a hierarchy. I bring in the fields (MTD, YTD, ITD) using the code below. I'm at my wits end, any ideas?

```
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EffectiveDate >=  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())), 1) THEN ''MTD'' ELSE ''Not MTD'' END) OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate) AS MTD
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EffectiveDate >=  DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) THEN ''YTD'' ELSE ''Not YTD'' END) OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate) AS YTD
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN EffectiveDate >=  DATEFROMPARTS(2013, 1, 1) THEN ''ITD'' ELSE ''Not ITD'' END) OVER (PARTITION BY EffectiveDate) AS ITD
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

EDIT:
Sample data

| Building | Rentpaid | Complaint | BuildingExpense | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | blah | 4 | 1/1/2021 |
| A | 3 | blah | 6 | 4/1/2021 |
| A | 1 | NULL | 5 | 3/2/2022 |
| B | 2 | NULL | 4 | 7/12/2022 |
| B | 4 | blah | NULL | 10/2/2022 |

Desired Output (Power bi Matrix)

| Building | MTD | YTD | ITD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  |  |  |
| SUMRentTransactions | 0 | 1 | 6 |
| ComplaintCount | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| BuildingExpenseCount | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| B |  |  |  |
| SUMRentTransactions | 4 | 6 | 6 |
| ComplaintCount | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| BuildingExpenseCount | 0 | 1 | 1 |

.

Comment: The rest of your data and a  desired output would really help. If you are looking for customer number, customer name, then MTD, YTD, ITD it would be different then other outputs.

Comment: @RobertShannon I hope my edit helps?

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of max, you want case sum coalesce.

so something like

```
sum(coalesce(case when date > dateadd(day, -1, getdate()) rentPaid,0 end,0)) as MTD
```

Repeat that for all the other cases.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you for taking the time to help me on this! I should clarify though that I more so need help with putting this data into a power bi visual in an easy to digest format. It seems a matrix was my best option but I can't seem to format/get it to display correctly (how I want it to look, with MTD, YTD, ITD all displayed at once). If you have the time, I would love to hear your suggestions.